# Export SQL Table using syntax to Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I found the following on Stack OverFlow.  It did not work because of a security error

Code:

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
                       'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\\bulkInsert\\testing.xls;',
                       'SELECT \* FROM \[Data$\]') 
    SELECT * 
    FROM ShippersCODE
```

I get this error from SSMS 2019:

> SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration

How can I change the security configuration? I don't know how to change security configuration

Thank you,

John Serrano

Comment: Have you searched for 'SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT OpenRowset'?